# Is this logical approach right for my program?

Tags: c, logic

Program - Rotating matrix 90 degrees clockwise.
I am a beginner in coding. I came across this question on GeeksforGeeks. I found the solutions very complex so tried applying my logic. But I don't know if my logic is appropriate for the program. Kindly guide me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int  A = 0 , a = 0 , b = 0;
    int arr[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    printf("90 Degree rotation: \n");
    printf("\n");
    for(A = 2; A >= 0; A--)
    {
        for(a = 0; a < 3 ; a++)
        {
            for(b = 0; b < 3 ; b++)
            {
                if(b==A)
                    printf("%d\t",arr[a][b]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Input

> 1 2 3
>   4 5 6
>   7 8 9

Output

> 3 6 9
>   2 5 8
>   1 4 7

Comment: why not just inverting a & b loops and drop the outer loop? you have 1 loop too many. or just print `arr[b][a]`. Well, maybe you have to reverse some indices, but should not be more than 2 loops to do that.

Comment: Questions about improving working code belong on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: That's counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is you matrix, with the axis you chose :

```
  b ->
a 1 2 3
| 4 5 6
V 7 8 9
```

That is, for a fixed `a` for instance, if you increase `b`, you print "the next number" (provided `b` is not `2`). Similarly, if you increase `a` with the same `b`, you take the same column, but the next line.

So, you can have the following pseudo program, to print a full column (on a line):

```
print_column(b):
  for a from 0 to 2
    print arr[a][b]
  print newline
```

What do you want ? You want to print the following :

```
3 6 9
2 5 8
1 4 7
```

That is printing the last column, then the middle one, then the first one, which is done by the following pseudo-program:

```
print the 3rd column of arr
print the 2nd column of arr
print the 1st column of arr
```

or, more concisely :

```
for b from 2 to 0
  print the b-th column of arr.
```

So, the final pseudo code is (inlining the print_column procedure):

```
for b from 2 to 0
  for a from 0 to 2
    print arr[a][b]
  print newline
```

Or, in C:

```
for(b = 2; b >= 0 ; b--)
{
    for(a = 0; a < 3 ; a++)
    {
            printf("%d\t",arr[a][b]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```